# CSS - center elements displayed with {display: table}

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display several `<div>` tags (with `<img />` tags inside them in a grid like fashion, where they are side by side until the end of the parent element, at which point the next `<div>` would wrap.

I have the code:

```
<div style="text-align:center; height: auto; ">

  <div style="display: table; margin: auto">

    <div style="width: 200px; height: 250px; float: left;">
      <img src="image1.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
    </div>
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 250px; float: left;">
      <img src="image2.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
    </div>
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 250px; float: left;">
      <img src="image3.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
    </div>
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 250px; float: left;">
      <img src="image4.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
    </div>
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 250px; float: left;">
      <img src="image5.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
    </div>
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 250px; float: left;">
      <img src="image6.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
    </div>
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 250px; float: left;">
      <img src="image7.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

And the output is almost there. The `<div>` elements are wrapping as expected, but they do not center as expected.

My question is: what do I need to do to get this 'grid' of `<div>` elements to be centered, yet still displayed in a grid-like format?

I've seen a few other SO question pertaining to this, but none of them solve my issue - or rather they describe slightly different issues.

Comment: We'd need to see your current CSS...ideally in a JSfiddle.net demo. However, try removing the `float:left` and replace wit `display:inline-block`

Comment: @Paulie_D http://jsfiddle.net/RjhDL/ All the CSS are inline styles at the moment.

Comment: See my amended comment

Comment: @Paulie_D That did it! Place it in an SO answer and I'll accept! (Never used inline-block before)

Comment: No problem. Just mark the existing answer as correct. He did that as I was doing my comment.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/ here is some resource that is helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating the divs keeps them from centering... Instead, make your wrapper div `text-align: center`, and the divs inside as `display: inline-block`. No need for `display:table`

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ceL79/

Answer (score 0):

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3C6kt/

```
HTML

<div class="center_wrap">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

CSS

.center_wrap {
  width:500px;
  text-align:center;
}

.box {
  width:100px; height:100px;
  background:#999;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

You can insert images inside div's then...